# Cannot get foreground color of NSTextView

Tags: swift, runtime-error, nstextview, color-space, nscolor

I am trying to use the code that follows to get the foreground color of an NSTextView. Unfortunately I get a runtime error that must be related with the involved color spaces. How can I fix m

```
if let textStorage = textView.textStorage {
    let rowObj = textStorage.paragraphs[row]
    let range = NSMakeRange(0, rowObj.string.characters.count)
    colorOrRowBeforeSelection = rowObj.foregroundColor!                
    if(rowObj.foregroundColor != nil) {
        let r = rowObj.foregroundColor!.redComponent
        let g = rowObj.foregroundColor!.greenComponent
        let b = rowObj.foregroundColor!.blueComponent
    } else {
        Log.e("cannot get foreground color components")
    }
} else {
    Log.e("textStorage = nil")
}
```

I get the following runtime error:

> [General] *** invalid number of components for colorspace in initWithColorSpace:components:count:

Answer (score 0):

I made it working with the following:

```
let components = UnsafeMutablePointer<CGFloat>.allocate(capacity: 4)
rowObj.foregroundColor!.getComponents(components)
let c = NSColor(colorSpace: NSColorSpace.sRGB, components: components, count: 4)
components.deinitialize()
components.deallocate(capacity: 4)
let r = c.redComponent
let g = c.greenComponent
let b = c.blueComponent
```

EDIT: I made a fix on the memory handling, now the code works except from the fact the it turns what should be white (in the *grey color space*) into yellow... hope someone can fix that.